Drift of reverse SDE with Lévy processes ($\alpha$ stable distributions)
Given an SDE with a Lévy process with a drift $b(x,t)$ the reverse SDE will have a drift, $\tilde{b}(x,t)$, given by the relation:
$$\tilde{b}(x,t) = - b(x,t) + \int_{\mathbb{R}} y \left( 1 + \frac{P_t(x+y)}{P_t(x)} \right) \nu (dy)\tag{1}\label{482595_1}$$
where $\nu (dy)$ indicate the Lévy measure. For an $\alpha$ stable process $\nu (dy) = \frac{C_{\alpha}}{|y|^{1+\alpha}} dy$. I'm interested in the case $1 \leq \alpha \leq 2$.
Substituting the form for the Lévy measure in \eqref{482595_1}, the integral on the r.h.s. has a diveregence as the integrand diverges for $y \approx 0$.
How should I proceed then to have a non pathological integral in order to derive the precise expression for the backward drift term?
Note: This question has also been posted on Mathematics. As of now, it remains unanswered there as well.

crossposted, please don't do that; https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4999287/87355

Hi @CarloBeenakker! I understand the concern, but this topic fits both communities and could benefit from their unique insights. Since the questions are still unanswered, posting in both increases the chance of finding a solution. Could you clarify why choosing just one is preferred here? Thanks!

there are two issues here, both to avoid wasteful duplication of efforts: firstly, you want to wait before cross-posting, the recommendation is a one week wait, perhaps shorter, but not a few hours; secondly, you really need to disclose the crossposting, with a link on both sites.

@CarloBeenakker, I added a link referring to the unanswered question in the other community, following your suggestion.
